# minimum permission to create AKS cluster

Tags: permissions, azure-aks, roles, minimum

what could be the minimum permission required to create AKS cluster?

Need to know the list of "Job function roles" to be attached with the app(created in App Registration) and those roles should be minimum.

Tried with contributor role only. Not much familiar with Azure cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have the contributor role assigned to your id in Azure, you can create an AKS cluster without any issue as the Contributor role provides broad permissions.
If you want to specifically choose selective Job function roles for your cluster, you can use the Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin role, which will allow you to create and manage AKS clusters but doesn't grant broad permissions across the entire Azure subscription. Below is the list of Job function
roles.
Home-> Kubernetes-> Access Control (IAM)-> Add Role assignment-> Job Function roles
[image]
[image]

You can also verify your current roles under subscription-> your-subscription-name->access-control(IAM)->View my access
[image]

This is a sample cluster on AKS with these roles enabled
[image]

FYI- If you need to interact with other resources outside of AKS, you might need additional roles or a combination of roles.

To understand better check this MS reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275541/general-query-privileged-administrator-role-vs-job)

Reference MS Docs:

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions-list)
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)

Comment: Thanks fro the answer. Now the problem is I am not able to assign multiple job function roles to service principal, how can it be done ?any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to assign multiple roles to SP at once? If yes then as far I know Azure Portal does not provide a direct option to assign multiple roles to a service principal at once.

Comment: Yes If I want to assign multiple job function roles to my SP. is Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin role minimum enough to create/destroy or manage AKS cluster ? Actually I thought  it can be more minimised by adding multiple job functions role so tried to add multiple job function role like for networking, storage management, etc.

Comment: No Schatt, multiple job function roles cannot be to SP. Both from portal or CLI you have to do it one at a time. Also you don't need multiple roles, usually if you have contributor role, you are sorted.

Comment: okay thanks . let me try with Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin role.